# What to do if a game changes completely?

Tags: discussion

[Starbound](http://playstarbound.com/) has recently released an update (Upbeat Giraffe) that changes approximately 90% of the game, and so most questions on the older release (Enraged Koala) are either less pertinent or no longer apply. Is there any protocol we have (or should have) that covers such a large change?

Comment: It's generally question by question.  One option for old questions that are still valid, but have incorrect answers is to offer a bounty.

Answer (score 0):

We do the same as we did for Minecraft. If an old question is still relevant but the answer **isn't**, add a bounty to encourage new answers. Leave outdated question and answer pairs for posterity, and make sure new questions and answers clarify what version of the game they are referring to.

Comment: There was another game that had this exact thing happen about 6 months ago, but for the life of me I can't find the meta question pertaining to it. I believe the consensus was if the game can still be played in the old state, the questions should stay, otherwise they should be closed or historic-locked. I'll see if I can dig it up

Comment: @Robotnik Historic locks wouldn't be appropriate; we'd just delete them.

Comment: @Robotnik I believe that was about Spiral Knights, and how the removal of the energy system rendered a lot of the old questions useless.